# Return unrestangularized objects for all routes by default

Tags: angularjs, restangular

Is there a Restangular configuration that will let me return plain objects by default for all routes?

I know I can add **addElementTransformer** on each route, but this seems to violate DRY.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for setResponseExtractor.

https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#how-can-i-access-the-unrestangularized-element-as-well-as-the-restangularized-one

I haven't tested their example but it looks promising for your needs. It's as follows:

```
RestangularProvider.setResponseExtractor(function(response) {
    var newResponse = response;
    if (angular.isArray(response)) {
        angular.forEach(newResponse, function(value, key) {
            newResponse[key].originalElement = angular.copy(value);
        });
    } else {
        newResponse.originalElement = angular.copy(response);
    }

    return newResponse;
});
```